# Cheap Implementation for the Moore Penrose Pseudoinverse

Tags: inverse, pseudoinverse

## Can some one explain Adam W's implementation for finding the Moore Penrose Pseudoinverse?

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75789/what-is-step-by-step-logic-of-pinv-pseudoinverse/317053#317053

https://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/ACheapimplementationforthePenrose.htm

I understand the rough Implementation. What is e subscript j? Does it stand for an arbitrary Euclidean Vector?

Comment: I think $e_j$ is the $j^{th}$ column of the identity matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: What is the purpose of Matrix B?

Comment: It's not clear to me.

Comment: If the transpose of B serves as the pseudoinverse in the second proof, does B subscript i represent a row of B or a desperate matrix entirely. "take a column of Bi and orthogonalize against the columns of A." Grammatically, it sounds like he is referring to a separate matrix. It would make more sense if they were columns of the same matrix B.